# What is the value of x when the CDF and the survival curve intersect?

Tags: survival, cumulative-distribution-function

[image: value at intersection]
How do you interpret the value of x at the intersection ? what is the mathematical proof?

Comment: You know the survival function. You know cdf. Equate them. See what happens.

Comment: The graphic is incorrect: no CDF and survival function can possibly be related as shown.  Conceivably you have used two different methods of *estimating* them and those methods are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: If the CDF is $P(X \le x)$ and the survival curve is $P(X \gt x)$ then they should sum to $1$ and mirror each other.  Your illustration almost does this but for some reason has a smother CDF than survival function

Answer (score 2):

One way to get to an answer is to figure out an expression of the survival function as function of the CDF (or the other way around). A resource where you could read about this relation between survival curve and CDF is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function . Once you have written down that relationship it becomes a simple algebraic task to add an additional relationship `cdf = survival and compute the value.

Another way could be to use the graphic, but the graphic does not contain sufficient detail and would lead to a wrong answer.